# Classic asp: assigning value to a session variable

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7

I have this weird problem, which I never encountered before. Fairly simple operation, which now all of the sudden gives me a headache:

```
Session("myVar") = Request.Form("myFormVar")
```

This gives me an error "Error occured, please contact the administrator... blabla"

I was trying different approaches and the only way I can temporary make it work is to just double the statement:

```
on error resume next
```

`Session("myVar") = Request.Form("myFormVar")`

`Session("myVar") = Request.Form("myFormVar")`

This 'works' but it's not a clean longterm solution.
The page is a redirect page where I do some actions and redirect to a result page. I just can't figure out what is happening. Did anybody encounter something like this before?

Thanks!

Comment: `on error resume next` is *NOT* "temporary make it work".  It's *MASKING* the error!  You need to determine 1) what's the value of 'Request.Form("myFormVar")' (and if myFormVar is even defined!), then 2) the specific error (error number, and error message).

Comment: Enable `Send Errors To Browser` in `IIS > ASP` for more detailed errors.

Comment: I know what the value of Request.Form("myFormVar") is, it is defined. I don't get a specific error number, if I would get, I would be much further on this issue. As you can see in my sample code, Session("myVar") is being assigned the correct value, but on the first line, it gives an error

Comment: It just gives me the error defined in IIS > ASP > Debugging properties > Script Error Message

Comment: @user9671207 Try adding `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />` in `web.config` under `system.webServer`

Comment: Additional info: it works on my local IIS (Windows 10) but fails on our Win 2008 IIS 7.5

Comment: Without the detailed error it's hard to give an answer, but try assigning `Request.Form("myFormVar")` to a variable first: `Dim myFormVar : myFormVar = Request.Form("myFormVar")` then set the session using the `myFormVar` variable: `Session("myVar") = myFormVar`

Answer (score -3):

Ok, I solved it. In my code I had Request("myFormVar") iso Request.Form("myFormVar"). I changed it and now it works fine. However, it's strange that it works on local IIS in Win 10 and it used to work on Win 2008 IIS 7.5 and now not anymore. I was told that some security patching has been done on our servers, so maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: Apologies, but the answer makes about as much sense as the question.

Comment: What does make no sense? Apologies but I can’t put it any simpler.

Comment: @user9671207, it makes no sense because you did not provide context regarding why it solved your problem.  Something else had to be going on that caused your previous error to occur.